# GIMP: Remove text from background

Tags: gimp, text, background

Im completely new to image editing, so excuse my immaturity...
I have the following image:[image]

I want to remove the writing on the blackboard and replace it with something different, keeping the original texture/smudges of the blackboard. What is the most efficient way for this in Gimp. I've tried for the last two hours and am becoming very angry because I can't get anything to work. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One way of doing it is to use the clone tool([image: Clone tool]). This tool basically lets you choose a source to copy from, then use it like a brush to paint the source over the destination.

To select a source, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Click</kbd> with the cursor over the source, then you can begin drawing over the destination.

In this case, you have to make sure that the source is a part of the blackboard without text and looks similar to the part with text that you want to cover. and just draw normally over the text, adjusting the source when the image starts to look odd.

[image: Using the clone tool]

Result:
[image: Result]

I didn't do the whole image but this should give you an idea of how to achieve this.

Comment: thanks Polar1ty, that worked great and was way easier than i thought...

Answer (score 1):

tbh, the easiest way would be to source an image of a clear blackboard (but with the smudges and texture you want) and use that to replace the board in the background.

So look for some masking and layer blending tutorials for gimp, that should help you out a bit.

Comment: No - cloning as in the other answer is definitely  the way to go in this case. There is plenty of empty space on this board where to clone from - no need to find an image with a similar board, much less of masking the foreground.